# Enlarging Neighborhood of Disc Boundary to Disc Interior

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, compactness

I'm trying to fill in a detail of a proof I'm reading (Prop. A.4 in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*) and I stumbled into the following situation. We have a closed subset $C$ of the boundary $\partial D^n$ of an $n$-disc, and an open subset $U$ of $D^n$ such that $C \subset U$. I would like to show that for some $\epsilon>0$, the product $C \times [1-\epsilon, 1]$ in "spherical" coordinates $(r,\theta)$, where $r$ is the distance from the center of $D^n$ and $\theta \in S^{n-1}$, is contained in $U$. Essentially, we're "thickening" $U$ into the interior of the disc and trying to show that the thickened set is contained in $U$ for small enough $\epsilon$.

Here's my stab at a proof: Suppose that for all $\epsilon > 0$, the associated set is not contained in $U$. Then we can find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of points in $D^n$ such that $a_n \in [1- 1/n, 1] \times C$ for all $n$ and every $a_n$ lies outside of $U$. Since $D^n$ is compact we can pass to a convergent subsequence and show that the point $a$ of convergence lies inside $C$. Since $U$ is open and $a \in U$, the sequence must be eventually in $U$ and we reach a contradiction.

Is this a sound argument, and is there an easier way to get the same result? I feel like I've seen this argument used to prove some more general theorem that I might be able to apply directly to this situation instead of going into the weeds like I did above.

Comment: Yes, this is very much the standard sort of argument for this kind of thing.